# Show all articles from specified categories sorted/filtered by date

Tags: joomla-2.5, articles, article-manager

I am listing all articles from categories, which are in a specific categorie and have articles within.

So like within categorie news:

- Sports (1 article)
- Politics (2 article)
- etc. (12 article)

So sub-categories from news which has no articles doesn't get displayed. This functions can be set all within joomla itselfs.

What I am also looking for is that a user is able to filter all those for a costumized date. Like all articles from 1st August 2013 till now (or sth. like that). 
The opening date of the article should be the date to filter the list.

Comment: Have you found the way to do this without using a extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the exact solution you're looking for, but I recently used an extension called [Mod LCA](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists/10731), a module that displays all your articles by year, month, day etc. The free version has a backlink to the author, but the pro version is about $3, IIRC.

There might be other modules for you in the [Articles Structured Lists](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists) category from JED.

Comment: I also add to this - as I have used this module quiet a few times for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little bit old and target Joomal 2.7 but with Joomla 3.7 you could do the following (which might help you):

- Create a new module (Articles - Category)
- In the Modules tab switch the mode to "Dynamic"
- In the filtering Options adjust the Options "Date Range Field", "Start Date Range", "To Date" ...